# Why do firefox and chrome allow users to view saved passwords?

Tags: security, google-chrome, firefox, password-encryption

It seems like a very big security leak, as anyone can quickly go to the settings and with one click show the passwords of the original user.

I also don't see the benefit of it to the original user to show his saved passwords.

There isn't even an option to disable showing the passwords.

In firefox there is an option to use a master password, but still no option not to use a master password and still disable the feature to show the passwords.

I think it should have been saved encrypted with no simple way to decrypt it.

Comment: This question seems [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow; perhaps http://security.stackexchange.com/ is a better fit?

Comment: I agree, didn't know about it, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think it should have been saved encrypted with no simple way to decrypt it.

Clearly you must always be able to decode it, otherwise the browser wouldn't be able to do so and the feature wouldn't work.

What you are advocating is obfuscation. But obfuscation is ineffective.

> how many people out of 100 will be able to see the passwords within a minute

100.

It doesn't matter how complicated the decoding scheme is; if just one person can work out how to decode it (and there will always be one, even for obscure non-open-source software) they can provide a one-click tool to do the job.

If your attacker is a non-authorised user with fleeting access to the machine, they could download and run a tool to decrypt the password base in a few seconds - certainly barely any longer than it would take to look up the passwords in the UI.

So deploying obfuscation would make life less convenient for the genuine user, but not really any less convenient for the attacker. That's not a win.

> But if they forget it they can still log in with the already saved password. And if they want they can reset it from the site

So can an attacker (fleeting physical access or trojan). What's the threat model you're protecting against here?

Comment: Still, to hack it with a tool will require to download the tool or run it from another media, and disable the antivirus before, and delete traces in the history of the browser and event log. Anyway, you are right, the threat exists anyway, now it lets me think saving passwords should be disabled by default and when enabled inform the user it can easily be shown. The current situation is that the browser encourages the user to save the password. And almost all users don't know it could be hacked easily.

Answer (score 1):

There are many users who generally keep difficult password and forgot it. By showing them their saved password, it helps them to recover the access to their account easily. While saving the password, it first asks for it. So, user should be intelligent enough to act accordingly if he is using his personal system or using third party system.

Comment: But if they forget it they can still log in with the already saved password.
And if they want they can reset it from the site. This is a lot safer than revealing the actual password with just few clicks.
It's enough that you leave your personal computer unattended for a minute to make someone see your passwords.

Answer (score 0):

You basic assumption is wrong, *"saved encrypted with no simple way to decrypt it"* is impossible. because they are open-source, the way to decrypt is made public, so anyone can easily decrypt it.

Instead fooling the users with easily crackable encrypt, you are warned, the password can be easily retrieved, save it as your own risk, or not save it.

Comment: It depends how you define simple. If it was encrypted like that, how many people out of 100 will be able to see the passwords within a minute and without the option to install a utility to see them. It's about making it harder to get it, and showing the passwords by a few clicks of mouse button can't be easier, and you don't have to hack anything or leave traces. They could leave the warning but make it harder than that.